# aks-engine can't create internal load balancer

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I can't make aks-engine create load balancer for agent pool, service stays in **'pending'** state forever.

```
kubectl get svc -w
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.0.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        16m
nginx        LoadBalancer   10.0.249.248   <pending>     80:31190/TCP   13s
```

I can see only load balancer for master in the resource group. It's all deployed with pretty generic **aks-engine generate examples/kubernetes-custom-vnet.json** (just using existing vnet) and then ARM templates

Comment: i suppose your service principal doesnt have enough rights. any errors in the `kubectl get events`?

Comment: I even added 'sp' as owner to the agent subnet, let me get events after I will recreate cluster again asap, trying without custom vnet now;)

Comment: why do you care about subnet permissions? why not rg contributor? because it needs to create load balancer

Comment: contributor right to rq was the fix, thnx;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer to this particular issue was granting proper permissions (contributor, for example) to the aks resource group